# "Запомнить меня"

Tags: php, авторизация

Всем привет.
Занимаюсь переделкой формы авторизации, возник вопрос как правильно реализовать "Запомнить меня". Есть мысль при регистрации записывать хеш юзеру в куку и в базу, а затем при каждом заходе сравнивать хеши и если все верно, то генерировать новый хеш и обновлять его в куке и базе. Правда не знаю как тогда быть с ситуацией, если новый сгенерированный хеш сопрут и сразу же подставят для незаконной авторизации.
В инете к сожалению пока ничего путного ненагугли по этому вопросу, решил узнать тут у более опытных коллег как правильно и безопасно реализовывать это :)
**UP** от 1.04
Я тут подумал, мой вариант же будет работать только при условии, что запоминается только на одном рабочем месте, т.е. если "запомниться" на работе, то авторизация дома слетит, т.к. хеш поменяется же, и при авторизации дома слетит "запоминалка" на работе, т.к. хеш опять смениться. Как быть?

Comment: обычно это значит, что кука токена авторизации должна быть "постоянной" а не сессионной.

Comment: т.е. при авторизации устанавливать куку с максимальный временем жизни? или что значит "постоянной" ?

Answer (score 2):

У куки есть срок жизни, если он не указан - кука сессионная, если указан - кука "постоянная" в современном мире сессионные куки смысла не имеют (особенно в браузерах семейства chromium) т.к. при установке параметра "запоминать открытые вкладки" браузер не только восстанавливает открытые вкладки, но и восстанавливает "сессионные" куки (и даже SessionStorage).

Как вариант, можно передавать токен авторизации через ajax и хранить его в объекте js, тогда куку устанавливать не нужно. Но опять же, если вы запишите токен в поле формы, [как рекомендует викепедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#.D0.A1.D0.BA.D1.80.D1.8B.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.8B) или даже запишите ее в DOM с помошью js, то браузер может восстановить содержимое страницы.

Ещё вариант - может быть одним из правильных - комбинировать js вариант и куки с малым сроком жизни (но не слишком малым, скажем минут 10), в этом способе вы просто на открытой вкладке через setTimeout раз в минуту обновляете срок действия куки.

ps: варианты даны для обеспечения отключенной опции "запомнить меня", со включенной - просто выставляйте куку на большой срок жизни (обычно это от месяца до года) И обновляйте ее при каждом удобном случае.

в случае полностью безкуковой авторизации (например как предлагает @TheDoctor) есть одна большая, но решаемая проблема - не будет работать "открыть в новой вкладке" решение на вскидку - передать сигнал другим вкладкам при появлении новой используя LocalStorage, а при обновлении токена используя его же, передать этот токен всем открытым вкладкам.

Comment: про куки это да, так и планировал, если "запомнить" то время жизни побольше. еще возник новый вопрос, обновил шапку, как быть с таким, как сохранять "запомнить" на разных местах и при этом генерить для безопасности новый хеш

Comment: А кто мешает несколько авторизованных хэшей хранить для одного юзера ? Вообще проблема кражи хэша не самая острая, csrf куда острее

Comment: Ну да, в принципе можно и несколько актуальных хешей хранить и затем при заходе обновлять нужный. А как вы сами реализовывали "запомнить меня" ? Таким же принципом? Как кстати генерировать хеш, просто каждый раз кодировать рандомный набор символов каким нибудь мд5 ? (мд5 для примера, знаю что лучше им уже не пользоваться) PS: за csrf спасибо, не знал про такую тему )

Comment: @eicto, а я чего-то думал, что проблема с csrf - это вторичное, а острее считал проблему с xss. Ну, да... речь ведь в вопросе не о том ;)

Comment: IMHO, "запомнить меня" на разных местах это не проблема. В каждом из мест пользователь решает надо его сохранять или нет. Дома я с легким сердцем запоминаюсь, а за чужим компом нет. В итоге на домашнем компе у меня кука со сроком жизни год, а на "гостевом" только до закрытия браузера. 

Для увеличения криптостойкости куки можно *подписывать* её и при этом незачем хранить копию в базе! - см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, если "Запомнить меня", то пишется в куки, если нет, то в сессию. Т.к. сессия обычно на один сеанс браузера, а кука - на столько, сколько установишь в времени жизни.
А токены (твой постоянно генерирующийся хэш) нужны - вероятность что сопрут хэш, который валиден только на один запрос Крайне Мала!

Comment: мала, но возможна же ) вдруг нехороший человек сопрет и подставит куки для авторизации, у него же это получится

Comment: @Stuf, Проблема с кражей куков всегда была, тут уж каждый выдумывает как может; хороший вариант - прятать авторизационные куки под флаг `HTTPOnly` - легальному скрипту они не нужны (а если нужны - переделай скрипт, он плохо продуман), а взломщику их отдавать не надо.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что при HTTPOnly мой пхп будет видеть куки (надо же как то первый раз прочитать по куке при пришел), но при этом яваскрипт не будет видеть ?

Comment: @Stuf, True. Браузер в любом случае будет пересылать серверу и PHP куки, а вот JS не сможет прочитать куки с этим флагом.